# Evaluating $\sum 1/(2n+1)!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not sure how to evaluate the series. Apparently it equals the hyperbolic sin at 1, but I don't see it. Not sure if I need to start breaking down the factorial or how to even begin the problem.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at $e^x-e^{-x}$. Expand each exponential in the usual way. You will get a more general result.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the Taylor series of $sinhx$, you see that it is the summation of your title when $x$ is replaced by 1 (Which is allowed because 1 falls within the interval of convergence)